# Node.js MongoDB Express Mongoose App throwing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, mongoose

This question has a lot of sub-questions so please bear with me. I am way over deadline and I need to at least make some ground on this app. I am trying to store links to YouTube videos (with dates) in a MongoDB database and then access them each day (based on the date) and place them in a carousel.

This app has two views: the video carousel where the YouTube videos will be shown (this should make a GET request to the database); and the database view which: has a form to enter new video links with dates; shows data store comprising of YouTube links and dates; and allows the user to delete an entry if a new video for a specific date has to be entered.

My current code is thus:
The server.js file that runs the app is thus:

```
//grab express and Mongoose
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

//create an express app
var app = express();

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var database = require('./routes/database');

//view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//set up the connection to the static files
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //make the db accessible to the router
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        //req.db = db;
        next();
    });
    //set up the routing
    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/database', database);

//start the server on the port 8080
app.listen(8080);

//Send a message to the console
console.log('The server has started');
```

And then the code for the database route (database.js), where the video links and dates are entered, stored and shown (POST, GET, DELETE) is as follows:

```
//Set up Express
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var app = express();

//connect to the data store and the set up the database
var db = mongoose.connection;

//connect to the database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Mandela_Diaries');

//Create a model which connects to the schema and entries collection in the Mandela_Diaries database
var Entry = mongoose.model("Entry", new Schema({date: 'date', link: 'string'}), "entries");

mongoose.connection.on("open", function() {
    console.log("mongodb is connected!");
});


//The route for getting data for the database - GET form
router.get("/database", function(req, res) {
    //Send the current entries to the page
    Entry.find({}, function(err, entries) {
        console.log(entries);
        if(err) {
            res.status(404).json({"error": "not found", "err":err});
            return;
        }
        //res.json(data);
        res.render(
            './views/database.html', {"root": __dirname + ''}
            );
    });

});

//The route for posting data on the database - POST form
router.post("/database", function(req, res) {
    //test new post
    console.log(req.body);
    var newEntry = new Entry({entry: {'date': req.body.date, 'link': req.body.string}});
        newEntry.save(function(err, result) {
            if (err !== null) {
                //object was not save
                res.status(500).json({error: "save failed", err: err});
                    } else {
                res.status(201).json(result);
        };
    });
});
```

And the code for the index route (aka the home page where the video links will go into the carousel) (GET) is as follows:

```
//Set up Express
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

/*connect to the data store on the set up the database
var db = mongoose.connection;

mongoose.connection.on("open", function() {
    console.log("mongodb is connected!");
});*/

//create an express route for the home page at http://localhost:8080/
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('./views/index.html', {"root": __dirname + ''});
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then finally the html file for the database.html where the database is updated and shown is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>The Mandela Diaries</title>

            <!-- For IE8 compatability mode -->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

            <!-- To ensure that the website consumes all the space available inside the browser window -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <!-- The CSS files including Bootstrap and custom CSS -->
            <!-- The CSS Bootstrap CSS file -->
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
            <!-- The custom CSS files 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->

            <!-- External scripts -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/script.js"></script>


        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-s-12">
                        <h1>The Mandela Diaries Database</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-s-4">
                        <h3>Add Entry</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-s-12">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="date">Date: </label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="link">Link: </label>
                                <input type="string" class="form-control" id="link">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-s-12" id="entries">
                        <ul></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

And the html file for the home page where the carousel is shown is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>The Mandela Diaries</title>

            <!-- For IE8 compatability mode -->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

            <!-- To ensure that the website consumes all the space available inside the browser window -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <!-- The CSS files including Bootstrap and custom CSS -->
            <!-- The CSS Bootstrap CSS file -->
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
            <!-- The custom CSS files 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->


        </head>
        <body id="container">
            <div class="span8">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="yesterday"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="today"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="tomorrow"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
    </div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

I'm getting a bunch of errors even though the code runs. Firstly when I try access the index ('/') I get the error: `Error: Cannot find module 'html'`. And when I try to access ('/database') I get the error: `Cannot GET /database I don't know where am I going wrong here? I'm trying to extrapolate from a lot of tutorials, this one in [particular](http://mherman.org/blog/2014/12/31/node-and-mongoose-a-primer/#.VYQhgPmqpBc) but at this stage I am totally lost.

Comment: You might need some more clear standards.  If your looking for a scaffold that helps solve this  https://github.com/wolfdogg/expressBuilder. This will help confine your routes using the standards already outlined there, and its simple turn key, then you can apply your scripts and html to that scaffold, and be on with it.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `Cannot GET /database` is happening because the route you created is pointing to `/database/database/` since you do `app.use('/database', database);` and then, in you `routes/database` you do `router.get("/database", ...`. 
You can solve this by changing your `routes/database.js` file to get `/` instead of `/database`.

Not sure if I made myself clear.

The other problem you have is that you are using `jade` as the view engine but your views are `html`. So you need to change your views to jade or change your view engine to html. Also, the path for your views is wrong since you are inside the `routes` folder and you want to go to `views` folder.

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for the response. I'm not getting what you're saying. I changed the code in database.js to router.get("/"..) and now I'm getting Cannot find module 'html'. What will be the best way to set the routers?

Comment: The problem isn't with your routers anymore.

Comment: I made this [gist](https://gist.github.com/joaosamouco/1afd05fa0db1350284aa) and updated my previous answer. Hope it can help.